# How to revert jQuery formatted number back to initial value when posting the form?

Tags: jquery, html, playframework-2.0

In a play 2 application I have some input texts where user can enter numbers and I want to format thousands.

```
<label>More than (X) favorites</label>
@helper.inputText(alertForm("alertSearchFields.moreThanXFavorites"), 
                        'class -> "form-control",
                        '_help -> "",
                        'placeholder -> ""
)
```

For this I use jQuery-number plugin from [here](https://github.com/teamdf/jquery-number/).

I'm doing the format of those inputs like this:

> $('#alertSearchFields_moreThanXFavorites').number( true, 0 );
>   $('#alertSearchFields_moreThanXFollowers').number( true, 0 );
>   $('#alertSearchFields_moreThanXRetweets').number( true, 0 );

so basically when a user will enter 3222 it will appear 3,222. The issue is that my controller expects number there:

```
"moreThanXFollowers" -> optional(number),
"moreThanXRetweets" -> optional(number),
"moreThanXFavorites" -> optional(number),
```

there if will trigger an error:

> Numeric value expected

I have checked the POST of the form in Developer Tools - Network and indeed the value of these fields, when thousands, are POSTed with formmatted value: 3,222 instead of 3222.

Is there any way to solve this? I know that a way would be to use ajax and format the number before sent, but this require to change some code, isn't there any other solution? Also another way would be to expect string on the server side and convert to number, but this is ugly, I want to avoid this.

**UPDATE**: What I find to be strange is that, if I do an alert like this when posting the form:

```
alert($('#alertSearchFields_moreThanXFavorites').val());
```

the value in alert window is no longer formatted (its 3222 instead of 3,222). Then why when POSTING is still formatted for thousands?

Comment: *"...but this require to change some code...Also another way would be to expect string on the server side and convert to number, but this is ugly, I want to avoid this."* You're going to *have* to change some code *somewhere*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ajax and server-side options are both valid choices. I'd probably handle it server-side if it were me.

Another option is to have hidden fields in your form you fill in on the `submit` event, and have those fields be the ones your controller actually uses.

E.g., suppose you have:

```
<input type="text" id="alertSearchFields_moreThanXFavorites" name="moreThanXFavorites">
```

You might change that to:

```
<input type="text"   name="moreThanXFavorites" id="alertSearchFields_moreThanXFavorites">
<input type="hidden" name="val_moreThanXFavorites">
```

And have the server-side use the `moreThanXFavorites_val` field's value.

Your `onsubmit` might look something like this:

```
$("selector for the form").on("submit", function() {
    var $form = $(this);
    $form.find('[name^="val_"]').each(function() {
        var $display = $form.find('[name="' + this.name.substring(4) + '"]');
        $(this).val($display.val().replace(/,/g, ''));
    });
});
```

In the above, I'm doing this:

- Handling the `submit` event
- Finding all elements (which I assume to be fields) in the form with `val_` at the beginning of their names; I'll call these the "hidden fields"
- Looping through those, finding the displayed field with the same name without `val_` (`.substring(4)` removes the first four characters on the string).
- Setting the value of the hidden field to the value of the displayed field

Note that that assumes your thousands separator is `,`, as it is in some locales; other locales use `.`, so if that may be a factor for you, you'll want to allow for it.

Comment: Thanks this works. It works even without having to substring but just using .val().

Comment: @CristianBoariu: I'm not following, how do you mean it works without the `substring`? You need that to find the related display element for the hidden element...

Comment: What I did is this: I've used hidden fields to copy formatted numbers into them and POST with the form. This copy of formatted number into not-formatted format just worked with $('#hidden_field').val($('#not_hidden_field').val()) so basically not hidden field's val return the not formatted value. And it just works.

Comment: @CristianBoariu: That shouldn't work. `val` returns the string unchanged, so all you're doing is copying `3,222` (or whatever) from one field to another, with the comma.